# mscoree.dll is missing on Windows Server 2003 SP2 Enterprise x64 even though .NET has been installed

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net-framework

I am currently working with a windows 2003 server and I am having issues running applications written on the .NET stack. Initially the framework for .NET 2.0 was installed, however, when attempting to run an msi, it bailed stating that it could not find the .NET framework.
Next I decided to try to install a later version of .NET (3.5) to see if that would work. However, this failed and complained that it could not find the mscoree.dll library.
I decided to back track and uninstall all versions of .NET and start fresh with 3.5. Unfortunately I hit the issue. So I tried again with .NET 2.0, since the installer successfully completed previously. Once again, the installer completed successfully. I attempted to install the application again, but the same issue. After applying all the necessary patches and still suffering from teh inablility to install the msi, I decided to dig through the .NET 2.0 installer logs. There were several 1603 errors reported (generic installer error message). I do not know where else to look. Has anyone experienced something along these lines (I fear that this may still be too generic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Microsoft CleanUp](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/d/e9d80355-7ab4-45b8-80e8-983a48d5e1bd/msicuu2.exe) before install .NET Framework.

Can you post log file to http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: For some reason I could not upload to pastebin. The text might have been too long. The CleanUp did get rid of the 1603 error message, but I still could not get past the problems. It has been decided to simply re-image the machine. You get the magic green check mark since you provided something helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having with installing or removing any versions of the .NET Framework, you should start [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/articles/454956.aspx), it is the most comprehensive guide to fixing .NET install issues that I've found. You may also want to check out the [.NET Framework removal tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/pages/8904493.aspx) It gives you a brute force way to get rid of .NET Framework installs that won't uninstall nicely.

Make sure you've removed all traces of .NET, and then install the latest version of 3.5, it will give you all the prior versions.

Here are the general steps that I used to rescue a totally messed up .NET install on XP:

2. Attempted to uninstall .NET Framework via Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs (failed)
3. Ran .NET Cleanup Tool cleanup_tool.exe, removed "All Installed Versions"
4. Renamed C:\Windows.NETFramework\V2.0xxx  to V2.0xxxx_backup
5. Made a backup of Registry key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NetFramework\  (regedit, file->export selected key to file)
6. Deleted HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NetFramework\  (via regedit)
7. Rename the GAC:  %WINDIR%\assembly  to %WINDIR%\assembly_backup
8. Run .Net Framework Installer
9. Ran netfx_setupverifier.exe (passed)